# ColModel jqgrid different label name

Tags: java, jquery, jqgrid

I'm using jqgrid to create grid. This one has 'main' one with headings and datas in it etc and 'advance search'. Unfortunately both of them are using same getColModel, and I want to have different heading and colname in advance search. For example I have something like this

```
getColModel: ->
    [ 
      {name:'dispId', label:  i18n('ProjectList.dispId'), classes:'grid_col', width:6, searchoptions:{sopt:filterOperators.string}, formatter: ((cellvalue, options, rowObject) -> "<a href=\"#{url("/project/#{options.rowId}/view")}\">#{cellvalue}</a>")}
```

]

and i18n('ProjectList.disp') displayes both in column and in column name in advance search. My English is really bad, but I hope you understand what I want to do - I want to have different headings in main grid and advance search option, and I would not like to change anything in jqgrid sources only in my own *.js scripts. (maybe some attribute in colModel? couldn't find a think and i was searching for solution alot)\

advance search option I called 'pager' I believe

I added this to my initgrid

```
afterRedraw: ->
                $("#{gridId} select").find("option[value='expectedRealizationDate']").html(i18n('ProjectList.expectedRealizationDate'))
                $("#{gridId} select").find("option[value='closing']").html(i18n('ProjectList.closing'))
```

it works but only when I open advance search, when I add new filter label names go blind again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jqGrid code in [`grid.filter.js`](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.filter.js) explicitly uses the colModel `name` and `label` to generate the options in the dropdown:

```
str += "<option value='"+that.p.columns[i].name+"'" +selected+">"+that.p.columns[i].label+"</option>";
```

So you are not going to be able to achieve what you want using the jqGrid API, unless modifications are made to jqGrid itself.

---

That said, without modifying jqGrid you might be able to hack around and use the [`afterRedraw`](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asinge_searching) function to replace the labels with custom ones. The code won't be pretty, but you might be able to get it working...

Comment: well i almost did it but still doesnt work so well. I added to my init grid `   afterRedraw: ->
    $("#{gridId} select").find("option[value='expectedRealizationDate']").html(i18n('ProjectList.expectedRealizationDate'))
    $("#{gridId} select").find("option[value='closing']").html(i18n('ProjectList.closing'))` it works but only until i "add" new option to search, when i close advance search and reopen it, then field names appeared, you know what am i doin wrong? I add this code to my main question cause somehow coding doesnt work for me here :|

Comment: Not sure offhand, perhaps you need to add another event handler. You might want to have a look at the docs and see if there is any other handler you can piggy-back on.

Comment: yeah meaby, but in doc "afterRedraw" = "[...]the filter is redrawed every time when we add or delet rules or fields" so it should work, thanks for an answer btw

Comment: Good point. You might want to try debugging it. There should be a version of jqGrid with full source as part of a single file in the downloaded zip, you could try using that one and debug with firebug. And no problem, just trying to help...

Comment: I found out that after adding filter theres only one function that is called.   `this.reDraw = function() {
   $("table.group:first",this).remove();
   var t = this.createTableForGroup(p.filter, null);
   $(this).append(t);
   if($.isFunction(this.p.afterRedraw) ) {
    this.p.afterRedraw.call(this, this.p);
   }
  };` after append the new filter are created and it doesnt go in if, i might not fully understand it but i think it should go into that if, if i add my function which is no longer null

Answer (score 1):

If someone would wonder how to do it heres an answer

```
$(@gridId).jqGrid('navGrid',@pagerId, {}, {}, {}, {}, {             
        afterRedraw: function() {
                $("select").find("option[value='expectedRealizationDate']")
                           .html(i18n('ProjectList.expectedRealizationDate'));
                $("select").find("option[value='closing']")
                           .html(i18n('ProjectList.closing'));
        }
} );
```